# Is it possible to get LaTeX to write "\" out

Tags: symbols

I need to write a backslach but LaTeX always wants a command after . Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Have you tried \textbackslash yet?

Comment: `\textbackslash` or `$\backslash$`